# React app doesn't recognizes NodeJs Backend

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, express

I have a react js app initialized with vite and I want to add a Node.js backend, however I can't, and when I add the index.js and run the command it only initializes the react and doesn't recognize posts and express routes. Can anybody help me? This is my App.jsx and my index.js:

App.jsx (it is initialized by main.jsx, but it is just vite code):

```
import { ResolutionList } from "./components/resolutions/ResolutionList";
import { ResolutionForm } from "./components/resolutions/ResolutionForm";
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route, Routes as Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import { SearchBar } from "./components/search/SearchBar";
import {Login} from "./components/screens/Login";

function ShowResolutions() {
  return (
    <>
      <ResolutionForm />
      <ResolutionList />
    </>
  );
}

function App() {
  
  return (

  
    <>
      <Router>  
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" element={<ShowResolutions />} />
          <Route path="/search" element={<SearchBar />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>

      
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The routes lead to react components that worked fine when I hadn't added the NodeJs server.
index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const { handleLogin } = require('./controllers/user.controller');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');



app.use(cors());


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3000);



app.set('app',path.join(__dirname, 'app'));



app.post('/api/login', handleLogin);

module.exports = app;
```

user.controller.js with the route to login:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const handleLogin = (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    console.log("username: ", username, "password: ", password);
  };


module.exports = {
    handleLogin
}
```

Update:
After doing what hyptf told me, my app launches in the correct routes but when I want to login a user it gives me:
`tp://127.0.0.1:5173/api/login 500 (Internal Server Error)`

This is the react login component:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export function Login() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

 
    fetch('/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
   
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {

          window.location.href = '/';
        } else {
        
          alert('Error al iniciar sesión. Por favor, intente nuevamente.');
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="username">Usuario:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="username"
          value={username}
          onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="password">Contraseña:</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

And the backend user post in index.js and handleLogin are submitted above.
I tried many solutions and tutorials (included ChatGPT) but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you used vite then you have a vite.config.js

You need to setup a proxy there.

This is what your vite looks like:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

add this after `plugins`:

```js
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:YOURPORT', //replace YOURPORT
    }
  },
```

Resources:
https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html

If you were using CRA:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said but now when I want to post an user in login, the console says "tp://127.0.0.1:5173/api/login 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Comment: I updated the question with new information.